# Why am I getting 'Unsupported argument errors' in my main.tf file?

Tags: terraform

I have a main.tf file with the following code block:

```
module "login_service" {
  source = "/path/to/module"

  name = var.name
  image = "python:${var.image_version}"
  port = var.port
  command = var.command
}
# Other stuff below
```

I've defined a variables.tf file as follows:

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  default     = "login-service"
  description = "Name of the login service module"
}

variable "command" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["python", "-m", "LoginService"]
  description = "Command to run the LoginService module"
}

variable "port" {
  type        = number
  default     = 8000
  description = "Port number used by the LoginService module"
}

variable "image" {
  type        = string
  default     = "python:3.10-alpine"
  description = "Image used to run the LoginService module"
}
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error when running terraform plan.

Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 4, in module "login_service":
│    4:   name = var.name
│
│ An argument named "name" is not expected here.

This error repeats for the other variables.  I've done a bit of research and read the terraform documentation on variables, and read other stack overflow answers but I haven't really found a good answer to the problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you sharing the variables.tf from root module `/path/to/module`, if not could you please share?

Comment: The module defined in the script is not a terraform module.  The terraform script is creating a kubernetes infrastructure in which a python module (Basically a microservice) will run in.  The directory containing the main.tf and the variables.tf file is where i ran terraform init.

Comment: What is your file and directory tree?

Comment: The path to my git repo is:  /home/<username>/src/repos/<reponame>.  Underneath that I have the src/scripts/terraform directory.  This is the directory where I ran terraform init.  There are two files in that directory, main.tf and variables.tf

Comment: Can you share the variables definition inside the module you referred to with `/path/to/module` ?

Comment: Hi.  Check the answer above.  The module in question is not a terraform module.

Comment: It is impossible to guess what are you trying to achieve and why you are getting this error. Apparently you are referring to a module that does not exist, or you might be setting the wrong path. Please provide more information about what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

A Terraform `module` block is only for referring to a Terraform module. It doesn't support any other kind of module. Terraform modules are a means for reusing Terraform declarations across many configurations, but th

Therefore in order for this to be valid you must have at least one `.tf` file in `/path/to/module` that declares the variables that you are trying to pass into the module.

From what you've said it seems like there's a missing step in your design: you are trying to declare something in Kubernetes using Terraform, but the configuration you've shown here doesn't include anything which would tell Terraform to interact with Kubernetes.

A typical way to manage Kubernetes objects with Terraform is using [the `hashicorp/kubernetes` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs). A Terraform configuration using that provider would include a declaration of the dependency on that provider, the configuration for that provider, and at least one `resource` block declaring something that should exist in your Kubernetes cluster:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
    }
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = "https://example.com/" # URL of your Kubernetes API
  # ...
}

# For example only, a kubernetes_deployment resource
# that declares one Kubernetes deployment.
# In practice you can use any resource type from this
# provider, depending on what you want to declare.
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "terraform-example"
    labels = {
      test = "MyExampleApp"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 3

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        test = "MyExampleApp"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          test = "MyExampleApp"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = "nginx:1.21.6"
          name  = "example"

          resources {
            limits = {
              cpu    = "0.5"
              memory = "512Mi"
            }
            requests = {
              cpu    = "250m"
              memory = "50Mi"
            }
          }

          liveness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/"
              port = 80

              http_header {
                name  = "X-Custom-Header"
                value = "Awesome"
              }
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 3
            period_seconds        = 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Although you *can* arrange resources into separate modules in Terraform if you wish, I would suggest focusing on learning to directly describe resources in Terraform first and then once you are confident with that you can learn about techniques for code reuse using Terraform modules.